# Generating a random directed graph

Tags: c#, graph

I wrote a function that returns a directed graph as an adjacency matrix. The function requires two arguments: the amount of nodes and the amount of edges. At first, nodes are placed and instantly connected to the graph. When all nodes are added, random edges are created until all edges are placed.

Code:

```
public int[,] GenerateMatrix(int Nodes, int Edges)
    {
        if (Edges < Nodes - 1) throw new Exception("Too few edges");
        if (Edges > Nodes * (Nodes - 1)) throw new Exception("Too many edges");

        int[,] adjacencyMatrix = new int[Nodes, Nodes];

        // Gives every cell a value of zero
        for (int y = 0; y < Nodes; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Nodes; x++)
            {
                adjacencyMatrix[x, y] = 0;
            }
        }

        int placedEdges = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < Nodes; i++)
        {
            // produce edge between rnd(0, amountofnodes) to new node
            int fromVertex = random.Next(0, i);
            int weight = random.Next(1, 10);

            adjacencyMatrix[i, fromVertex] = weight;
            placedEdges++;
        }

        while (placedEdges < Edges)
        {
            int fromVertex = random.Next(0, Nodes);
            int weight = random.Next(1, 10);

            int targetVertex = random.Next(0, Nodes);
            while (targetVertex == fromVertex || adjacencyMatrix[targetVertex, fromVertex] != 0) //|| adjacencyMatrix[fromVertex, targetVertex] != 0)// tredje condition tar bort parallella kanter
            {
                fromVertex = random.Next(0, Nodes);
                targetVertex = random.Next(0, Nodes);
            }

            adjacencyMatrix[targetVertex, fromVertex] = weight;
            placedEdges++;
        }

        return adjacencyMatrix;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. I think the difference in code indentation between the method head and the braces around its body unusual: please state, in comment or question body, whether it is intentional or not. If it is against your intentions, please heed [What should I [not\] do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: When picking a fromVertex that already has Nodes-1 outgoing edges, the while-loop won't terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my suggestions:

- `Nodes`, `Edges`: most of the time the function's parameters don't start with big letter. `nodes` and `edges` are more preferable.

  - Also consider to restraint the [possible range of these variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types). `uint` or even smaller like `ushort` might be a better fit for your use case.
- `throw new Exception`: It is good that you do preliminary checks. Usually the preferred Exception type is `ArgumentException` ([1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception)) to indicate that you have a problem with the calling parameters.
- `adjacencyMatrix`: You don't need to zero all of the entries inside this matrix because by default their value will be zero. (`int` is a value type with a default value `0`).

  - If you wish to clean the array, because you have received that for example via a parameter then you can use the built-in `Array.Clear` ([1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clear?#System_Array_Clear_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_)):
    `Array.Clear(adjacencyMatrix, 0, adjacencyMatrix.Length);`
- <s>`random.Next(0, i)`: Alternative: `random.Next() % i`</s>
- <s>`random.Next(1, 10)`: Alternative: `new Random().Next() * (10 - 1) + 1` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50347359/13268855))</s>
- `placedEdges++`: instead of increasing it every time you could initialize it with the proper value: `int placedEdges = Nodes -1;`
- `fromVertex` and `targetVertex`:

  - `fromVertex` + `toVertex`
  - OR `sourceVertex` and `targetVertex` would

  give more convenient naming.

Comment: Why do you recommend the alternative randomization? Is it faster? According to me random.Next(start, to) is more readable.

Comment: `random.Next(start, to)` has a good chance to be uniform - slim for `random.Next() % i`.

Comment: If you look at the source code of [Next()](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/random.cs#L131) and [Next(int minValue, int maxValue)](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/random.cs#L160) then you can see that the latter might call the `InternalSample` [twice](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/random.cs#L135) in some cases.

Comment: In this particular case it won't call it, so I can agree with you guys that calling random.Next with min and max values might be more convenient here.

Answer (score 3):

You describe what the code is to accomplish:
do so *in the code*, using what tool support works for you. MS is on an [XML spree](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc), [doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) currently has a .nl domain.

Omit *giving every cell a value of zero*:

> **The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero**,
> and reference elements are set to null.

You use *node* as well as *vertex* - [Peter Csala](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/254880/93149) already assessed mixing *from* and *target*.

For a uniformly pseudo-random non-negative number up to some *maxValue* call `int Random.Next(int maxValue)`.
Each and every edge from the first loop "points down", introducing a non-uniformity.

When picking a `fromVertex` that already has *Nodes-1* outgoing edges, the `while`-loop won't terminate.
Expect *many* trips though this loop when there are more than about Nodes^3/2 edges, anyway.
(*tredje villkoret undviker **anti**parallella kanter*)
(Not using anti-parallel edges would need to be taken into account in the initial (uncommented!) range check.)